# How can i identify the route from my .bat file

Tags: php, batch-file

So, i need to know how can i identify my test.bat file inside my project, what i'm trying to do is this:

```
<?php

$v1 = "test one"; //this is domain
$v2 = "test two"; 

$bat_file = "folder/test.bat ".escapeshellarg($v1)." ".escapeshellarg($v2);
$output = null;
system($bat_file, $output);

?>
```

bat file:

```
@echo off

set test1=%1
echo example one %test1%

set test2=%2
echo example two %test2%
```

i need to set a directory to find my test.bat file, how can i do this? i know if i remove the "/folder" i can do what i want, but what if i need to put a directory to my .bat file? how i'm supposed to do this?

Comment: Simply add `cd %~dp0` right after `@echo off` and it will set your active directory to the same directory you are running your script. From there everything is a relative path, so if you have a folder called `folder` you could run it like `folder/batchfile.bat`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, actually it should read `cd /D "%~dp0."` (note that the batch file might reside on another drive)...

Comment: @aschipfl I run a script hundreds of times a day on hundreds of models of computers, the script is always ran from a USB, and the code above works for me.

Comment: i did this `@echo off cd %~dp0` and this `@echo off cd /D "%~dp0." `
still, not showing the .bat in my test.php page.
just to let you guys know, my folders are just like this:

test.php
folder/test.bat

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, I didn't say it can't work, I just said `cd` doesn't change the drive without `/D`...

Comment: @Kenai, did you write this in a single line? if so, try `@echo off & cd /D "%~dp0."` instead...

Comment: @aschipfl I was saying I don't include `/D` in my script, which is _always ran from a different drive_, and it works fine on hundreds of different models of computers

Comment: @aschipfl i did, still nothing, the file is not displaying in the test.php view :(